# Pop the google login page in case there is no user logged in

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

My Android app has some in-app purchases the user can make but if the app is started on a device with no logged in user, the billing v3 API just returns error 3 "BILLING_UNAVAILABLE"
In this case my main options is to pop a message box to tell the user to go and log in to a google account but this is rather cumbersome.
Is there a way to just pop the google login page for the user?
I've see apps that use "Game Services" api (Achievements, Leaderboards etc') do that but my app still doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a `BILLING_UNAVAILABLE` response, you can try something like this to launch add Google account flow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT);
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_ACCOUNT_TYPES, new String[] {"com.google"});
startActivity(intent);
```